# How to achieve this in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to databases, but I am getting a problem:

Here  AAA, BBB, TABLE-1, TABLE-2 and TABLE-3 table names(tables).

```
TABLE-1 (A,   B) COMPOUND PRIMARY KEY(A,B) AND A IS REFER FROM *AAA(A)* AND B IS REFER FROM *BBB(B)*
         1    1
         1    2
         2    1

TABLE-2 (D,   A) D IS PRIME AND A IS REFER FROM *AAA(A)*
         1    1
         2    2

TABLE-3 (D,   B) COMPOUND PRIMARY KEY(D,B) AND B IS REFER FROM *BBB(B)*
         1    1
         2    2

HERE MEANING OF TABLE-2 AND TABLE-3 IS 
(D,   A,   B)
 1    1    1
 2    2    2
```

But the problem is in second row here A = 2, B=2 is not matching with TABLE-1.

How to achieve this?

Ex:

```
    I have Airport, Caterer, Meal, Airport_caterer_map, Airport_Meal_Map
    Airport (this main configuration table)
    id     Name
     1      aaa
     2      bbb
    Caterer   (this main configuration table)
    id     Name
     1      mmm
     2      nnn

    Airport_caterer_map  (this main configuration table)
    airport_id     caterer_id
    1                1
    1                2
    2                1

    Meal
    id     Name  caterer_id
     1      mmm  1
     2      nnn  2

    Airport_Meal_Map
    mail_id    airport_id
    1          1
    1          2
    2          1
    2          2   -- This row should be wrong. 

why is, 
   1. meal 2 is available in airport 2
   2. meal 2 is providing by caterer 2
   3. But there is no mapping between caterer 2 and airport 2 in airport_caterer_map table.
```

Comment: Each table has its meaning we cannot do such interpretation. Also if you have a real example it would be better for explanation.

Comment: If "MEANING OF TABLE-2 AND TABLE-3" is just a write-up, no actual table, this is nothing you need to worry about. Only if you end up with actual tables, AND can't combine the respective key (combination) values to reflect your problem domain, you need to get a closer look. If, however, this is actually a table, review, what it is supposed to express - and whether this needs to be in line with TABLE-1.

Comment: those are table names only

Comment: Paste CREATE TABLE statements into your question.

Comment: This looks like it has been abandoned in an unclear state, voting to close. Can be closed as unclear, too broad or lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your Airport_Meal_Map should actually be an Airport_Caterer_Meal_Map - if you want the database to help with the consistency checks:

```
CREATE TABLE Airport
  (
   id INT primary key,
   name VARCHAR(30)
  );

INSERT INTO Airport VALUES
(1, 'aaa'),
(2, 'bbb');

CREATE TABLE Caterer
  (
   id INT primary key,
   name VARCHAR(30)
  );

INSERT INTO Caterer VALUES
(1, 'mmm'),
(2, 'nnn');

CREATE TABLE Airport_Caterer_Map
  (
   airport_id INT,
   caterer_id INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (airport_id, caterer_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (airport_id) REFERENCES Airport(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (caterer_id) REFERENCES Caterer(id)
  );

INSERT INTO Airport_Caterer_Map (airport_id, caterer_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1);

-- INSERT INTO Airport_Caterer_Map (airport_id, caterer_id) VALUES
-- (2, 2);

CREATE TABLE Meal
  (
   id INT,
   name VARCHAR(30),
   caterer_id INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, caterer_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (caterer_id) REFERENCES Caterer(id)
  );

INSERT INTO Meal (id, name, caterer_id) VALUES
(1, 'mmm', 1),
(2, 'nnn', 2);

-- INSERT INTO Meal (id, name, caterer_id) VALUES
-- (1, 'mmm', 2);

-- INSERT INTO Meal (id, name, caterer_id) VALUES
-- (2, 'nnn', 1);

CREATE TABLE Airport_Meal_Map -- actually Airport_Caterer_Meal_Map
  (
   meal_id INT,
   airport_id INT,
   caterer_id INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (meal_id, airport_id, caterer_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (airport_id, caterer_id) REFERENCES Airport_Caterer_Map(airport_id, caterer_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (meal_id, caterer_id) REFERENCES Meal(id, caterer_id)
  );

INSERT INTO Airport_Meal_Map (meal_id, airport_id, caterer_id) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 1),
(2, 1, 2);

-- Fails as meal 1 is not prepared by caterer 2
-- INSERT INTO Airport_Meal_Map (meal_id, airport_id, caterer_id) VALUES
-- (1, 1, 2);

-- Fails as meal 2 is not prepared by caterer 1
-- INSERT INTO Airport_Meal_Map (meal_id, airport_id, caterer_id) VALUES
-- (2, 1, 1);

-- Fails as airport 2 is not served by caterer 2
-- INSERT INTO Airport_Meal_Map (meal_id, airport_id, caterer_id) VALUES
-- (2, 2, 2);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f23821/2/0)